# Passing NSString between views returns NULL

Tags: ios7, nsstring

I am trying to return an `NSString` between views. Code below:

**Data Source:**

.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *selectedDate;
```

.m:

```
@synthesise selectedDate;

-(NSDate *)date
{
    NSInteger monthCount = [self.months count];
    NSString *month = [self.months objectAtIndex:([self selectedRowInComponent:MONTH] % monthCount)];

    NSInteger yearCount = [self.years count];
    NSString *year = [self.years objectAtIndex:([self selectedRowInComponent:YEAR] % yearCount)];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM:yyyy"];
    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", month, year]];
    selectedDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", date];
    return date;
}
```

**Loading View:**
.m:

```
[VIEWNAME] *firstviewObj=[[[VIEWNAME] alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"%@",firstviewObj.selectedDate);
```

What is my issue??

Comment: looks like `-(NSDate *)date` never called and `selectedDate` not filled with proper value.

Answer (score 1):

```
Please do this
VIEWNAME *firstviewObj=[[VIEWName alloc]init];
NSDate *myDate = [firstviewobj date];
NSLog(@"%@",firstviewObj.selectedDate);

Remember myDate and firstviewObj.selectDate will give same result
```